# R: I don't know where the error is in this code

Tags: r, dplyr, forecast

i don't know what's wrong in this code

```
cement_cv <- aus_production %>%
  slice(1:(n()-4)) %>%
  stretch_tsibble(.init = 5*4, .step = 1)

fc <- cement_cv %>%
  model(ETS(Cement),
        SNAIVE(Cement),
        ) %>%
  forecast(h = "1 year")
```

```
fc %>%
  group_by(.id, .model) %>%
  mutate(h = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  accuracy(aus_production, by = c(".model", "h"))

Error in accuracy.default(., aus_production, by = c(".model", "h")) : 
First argument should be a forecast object or a time series.
```

I would be grateful for your help in pointing out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example to provide a minimum reproducible data for us to help.

Comment: Try `accuracy(object = ., x = aus_production, by = c(".model", "h"))` to make explicit that the incoming pipe data (`.`) are the forecast object and `aus_production` is the observed values to compare against.

Comment: You also should not have a comma after `SNAIVE(Cement)`